# onPropertyChange only working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events

`onPropertyChange` is only working in IE.  I used `onPropertyChange` for entering some text in one text box, at the same time same text displays in another text box. Are there any other methods are available to solve the problem?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="" maxlength="64"size="30" class="controlStyle" onPropertyChange="displayName(this, document.frmSkills.EmpLn, document.frmSkills.EmpDn,displayFormat)">
```

Comment: Have you tried binding to keyboard events? [jQuery Keyboard Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) will make it easy.

Comment: @DaniP. my requirement is when i enter some text in first text box, the same text follow in second text box. i want the solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the solution for above question, below is the code. thank you all for your kind reply.

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("textarea_one").onkeyup=function() {     
      document.getElementById("textarea_three").value=this.value+ " "+document.getElementById("textarea_two").value;
  }
  document.getElementById("textarea_two").onkeyup=function() {     
      document.getElementById("textarea_three").value=document.getElementById("textarea_one").value+" "+this.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other browsers support an event on any text-input event (oninput).

You'll need to handle both events to cover IE as well.

textelement.addEventListener('input',function,false)) or
textelement.oninput=

this is from:
http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php

> The oninput event is supported in Internet Explorer from version 9,
>   but  The oninput event is buggy in Internet Explorer 9
>
> The oninput is useful if you want to detect when the contents of a
>   textarea, input:text, input:password or input:search element have
>   changed, because the onchange event on these elements fires when the
>   element loses focus, not immediately after the modification. The
>   oninput event is supported in Internet Explorer from version 9. If you
>   need an event that fires when the contents of these elements are
>   modified in Internet Explorer before version 9, use the
>   onpropertychange event.
>
> The oninput event is buggy in Internet Explorer 9. It is not fired
>   when characters are deleted from a text field through the user
>   interface only when characters are inserted. Although the
>   onpropertychange event is supported in Internet Explorer 9, but
>   similarly to the oninput event, it is also buggy, it is not fired on
>   deletion. Since characters can be deleted in several ways (Backspace
>   and Delete keys, CTRL + X, Cut and Delete command in context menu),
>   there is no good solution to detect all changes. If characters are
>   deleted by the Delete command of the context menu, the modification
>   cannot be detected in JavaScript in Internet Explorer 9. Always use
>   the addEventListener method in Internet Explorer 9 to register an
>   event listener for the oninput event. The attachEvent method does not
>   work for the oninput event. The oninput event is not supported for
>   textarea elements in Safari before version 5, use the textInput event
>   instead in that browsers.

Comment: thanks alot.. how to use oninput event in my code, here is my code,                   <input type="text" id="EmpLn" name="EmpLn" value="<%=bean.getLastName().trim()%>" maxlength="64" size="30" class="controlStyle" tabindex="2" onPropertyChange="displayName(document.frmSkills.EmpFn, this, document.frmSkills.EmpDn,<%=displayFormat%>)">&nbsp;<img src="<%=ImageMappingManager.getImageName("imgMandatorystar")%>" width="8" height="8" border="0"></td>...               can you help me?

Comment: HI,i got the solution using following code , thank you all for you kind reply,                                                                         window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("textarea_one").onkeyup=function() {     
      document.getElementById("textarea_three").value=this.value+ " "+document.getElementById("textarea_two").value;
  }
  document.getElementById("textarea_two").onkeyup=function() {     
      document.getElementById("textarea_three").value=document.getElementById("textarea_one").value+" "+this.value;
  }
}